# Organize nodes in subdirectorys

Tags: rosrun, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I'm using ROS for a while now and I'm curious if it's possible to group packages in subdirectory and access them with rosrun. I already organized my code in theme-based folders in which the node folders are located. It appears that catkin has no problem with this structure whatsoever, but rosrun has. I added my src folder to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH but nothing is found. Is there a possibility to use this how I'm trying to? I know that I could just put all packages in the src folder and seperate them by name (like status_lights), but thats very messy. Has anyone a solution to my little problem?

Best Wishes,

Karl_Auer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203705/organize-nodes-in-subdirectorys/) by [Karl_Auer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4779/karl_auer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can organise your packages any way you want, `catkin` will crawl your directory structure and discover packages. `rosrun` should have no problem with this either, provided you have correctly sourced the `devel/setup.bash` after building your workspace. The only constraint is that `catkin` by default only looks for packages under the `src` directory in your catkin workspace.

> I added my src folder to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH but nothing is found.

If you use catkin to build, and source the `devel/setup.bash`, you should not need to set `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` yourself.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karl_Auer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4779/karl_auer/) on 2015-02-24**:
The part about sourcing devel/setup.bash came to me about 5 min after I posted the question.

I think i have correctly sourced it (just typed `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` ) , but when my packages are in subfolders they're not seen by rosrun

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-24**:
Have you rebuilt your workspace? After that, source the `devel/setup.bash` in new terminal. If `rosrun` then still can't find your packages, try a `rospack profile` (this rebuilds a cache).

Don't forget to remove any `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` lines from your `.bashrc`.